Is there a metacompact space that fails to be para-Lindelöf?
A space is metacompact provided every open cover of the space has a point-finite open refinement.
A space is para-Lindelöf (resp. paracompact) provided every open cover of the space has a locally countable (resp. finite) open refinement.
The $\pi$-Base does not have any known examples of metacompact spaces that fail to be para-Lindelöf, but knows four potential examples which fail to be paracompact: π-Base, Search for metacompact+~Paracompact+?Para-Lindelöf.
Is there an example of a metacompact space that fails to be para-Lindelöf, so as to witness a result at π-Base, Search for metacompact+~Para-Lindelöf?

Consider S87: Deleted Dieudonné plank, the subspace of S191: Dieudonné plank obtained by removing the point $\langle\omega_1,\omega\rangle$.
So $X=(Y\times Z)\setminus\{\langle\omega_1,\omega\rangle\}$
where $Y=[0,\omega_1]$ is given the topology with points of $[0,\omega_1)$
isolated and neighborhoods of $\omega_1$ cocountable,
and $Z=[0,\omega]$ is given the topology with points of $[0,\omega)$
isolated and neighborhoods of $\omega$ cofinite.
This space is known to be metacompact.
This space fails to be para-Lindelöf. To see this, let $U_{\alpha,n}=\{\alpha\}\times[n,\omega]$ and $V_{n,C}=([0,\omega_1]\setminus C)\times\{n\}$. Then $\{[0,\omega_1]\times[0,\omega)\}\cup\{U_{\alpha,0}:\alpha<\omega_1\}$ is an open cover, and any refinement of this cover must for each $\alpha<\omega_1$ include a set containing $U_{\alpha,n_\alpha}$ for some $n_\alpha<\omega$.
If this refinement was locally countable, then for each $n<\omega$, there must be a neighborhood $V_{n,C_n}$ of $\langle\omega_1,n\rangle$ missing all but countably-many $U_{\alpha,n_\alpha}$. Thus $n_\alpha>n$ for all $\alpha\in\omega_1\setminus C_n$. But then consider $\alpha\in\omega_1\setminus\bigcup_{n<\omega}C_n$: we have $n_\alpha>n$ for all $n<\omega$, a contradiction.
